# disable routing of SonataUserBundle/FosuserBundle

Tags: symfony

I hope to customize authentication links in my sf2 project, I use SonataAdmin SonataUserBundle(backend) and FosuserBundle + HWIOAuthBundle(facebook login), I created a accoutbundle bundle and here is my controller :

```
class ConnectController extends Controller
{

public function loginAction()
{

    //login code
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    /* @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
    $session = $request->getSession();
    /* @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */

    // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = '';
    }
   .....
```

To create my own login page and here is my app/config/routing.yml :

```
admin:
resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_security:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_security_1.xml"

sonata_user_resetting:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_resetting_1.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

sonata_user_profile:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_profile_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user_register:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_registration_1.xml"
    prefix: /register

sonata_user_change_password:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_change_password_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

#HWIOAuthBundle routes
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /login

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix: /login

facebook_login:
     pattern: /login/check-facebook

facebook_connect:
     pattern: /login/facebook

account_connect:
     pattern:  /connect
     defaults: { _controller: AcmeAccountBundle:Connect:login } //personalized link does not work
```

so the problem that link of login page /app_dev.php/login it does not point to "account_connect" but he always go to the sonata user login page,so my question here is how to disable the sonatauserbundle rounting without change anything in my **vendor folder**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing always mach with first entry in table. I think the best way to change routing in bundle which is in vendor folder is override part of it.

See here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html